# How to get ViewRef values in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript

So I'm trying to build a dynamic form in Angular2 (and NativeScript)..

### What i've done so far is:

- Get JSON from REST API
- Add Component (via a template) to the ViewContainerRef

Now I want to "submit" the form. To do this, I thought I could simply use the ViewContainerRef and get its "siblings" (which are dynamically created based on the before mentioned JSON) and loop through them and create a JSON object to post this.. But I don't understand how the Angular2 DOM works..

Here is the (partial) code I've got so far:

---

**addComponent function**

```
//... class DynamicComponent, has id and value properties
public addComponent(container: ViewContainerRef, template: string){
    @Component({template: template})
    class TemplateComponent{
        public value = "test";
    }

    @NgModule({declarations: [TemplateComponent]})
    class TemplateModule {}

    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TemplateModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.filter((comp)=>
        comp.componentType === TemplateComponent
    );
    const component = container.createComponent(factory[0]);
    return TemplateComponent;
}
```

---

**Create Components**

```
@ViewChild("container",{ read: ViewContainerRef }) container : ViewContainerRef;
..

//foreach JSON element
let _component = <any>
    this._dynamicComponent.addComponent(
        this.container, elementObject.render()
    );
//the render() returns things like : `<Label text="foo"></Label>`
.. 

_component.prototype.onTap = () => {
    this.submit();
}
```

---

**Submit Function**

```
submit(){
      let json=[];
      for(let i=0;i<this.container.length;i++){
        let component = this.container.get(i);
        //Ideally I want to do this:
        /*
          json.push({
            id:component.id,
            val:component.value
          });
        */
      }
}
```

---

Basically, I get "component" in the submit function as a ViewRef object, but how do I continue from there?

Also, I'm fairly new to Angular2, so is this the right way? I've seen the form builder but I didn't get it to work properly with dynamically created elements..